# Prove a set is open, closed, or neither

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

After proving $A=\left(\frac{2n+5}{3n+1}:n\in\Bbb N^+\right)= \left(\frac{7}{4},\frac{9}{7},\frac{11}{10},1,\frac{15}{16},\frac{17}{19},…\right)$ is convergent and a Cauchy sequence, I want to know if this set is an open set, closed set, or neither.

I know that the definition of an open set is "**Definition 3.2.1** (Stephen Abbott “Understanding Analysis”) A set $O\subseteq \Bbb R$ is open if for all points $a \in O$ there exists an ϵ-neighbourhood $V_ϵ (a)\subseteq O$."

and for closed set is "**Definition 3.2.7** (Stephen Abbott “Understanding Analysis”) A set $F\subseteq\Bbb R$ is closed if it contains its limit points"

$A$ isn't an open set because if we pick $a=1$ there's no $V_ϵ (1)$ in $A$. (Can someone please help me to word this more correctly?)

But for proving if $A$ is a closed set or not I had to find the limit points first based on the definition I used. I still don't understand how to find a limit point. By reading the definition in the book, I still couldn't understand how. Here's the definition : "**Definition 3.2.4.** A point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if every ϵ-neighborhood
$V_ϵ(x)$ of $x$ intersects the set $A$ in some point other than $x$."

Then after proving that, I also need to find the isolated points too, so the limit point is still necessary for me to find.

Comment: The limit of the sequence is $\dfrac{2}{3}$. Is this in your set? If not, then the set is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Limit points precisely capture the intuition of a point "being the limit of a non-constant sequence". If you suspect this set is not closed (hint: you should suspect this), then what you should do is find a point outside of this set which is a limit of a sequence of points inside the set.

Comment: Is all the limit point of $A$ is $\frac {2}{3}$?  $\frac {2}{3}$ is not in the set, so the set isn't closed. Then $A$ is consisted of only isolated points. Does that seem right?

Comment: @Novita12 Yes, exactly. Make sure to prove that $2/3$ is actually a limit point, and to prove that it isn't in the set.